# What is wrong with fwrite or fputcsv

Tags: php

I have been trying to make it work with either fwrite or fputcsv but i always get the errors pointing to parameters. I am newbie in php but I try to experiment and see what it does. but so far it doesn't either work because of parameters or not writing to the file (nothing on csv file).

**I have one big problem. How to have text appear in columns (name, email and comments) while writing all data into three columns?**

```
$csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);
        foreach($csvData as $key => $val)
        {
            $strVal = $val;

        }
        print $strVal;
        $fileHandle="";
        $filename='I-have-question.csv';
        if(!file_exists($filename)){
            $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "a+");
        }

        fwrite($fileHandle, $strVal);
        fclose($fileHandle);
```

insight/guide would be appreciated. thanks

**EDIT**

```
$name=$_POST['contactName'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $comment=$_POST['comment'];


        $csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);
        $csvCol = array ('name', 'email', 'comment');

        $strVal='';
        foreach($csvData as $key => $val)
        {
            $strVal .= $val;

        }
        print $strVal;
        $fileHandle="";
        $filename='I-have-question.csv';

            $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "a+");


        fputcsv($filehandle,$csvData);
        fclose($fileHandle);
```

Now error says: Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null. I changed according to two inputs. But it doesnt go well.

**EDIT #2**

Thank you, @Baba and @Quasdunk for the inputs. The only question left is how to bring in the array for $csvCol to be appended to the first row for each column so that the csvData can be appended/written after that. Only once for csvcol. how do I go about it?

**EDIT #3**
Thank you very much for the help. I investigated on downloading csv from the browser after the user click on the link - is it possible to do that in that same code? or I hardcode the link to the csv? Just wonder. I saw somewhere about downloadable csv where I click submit button and then the file pop up to be saved - thats not what I want but I only need the csv file to be downloaded from the server via the link.

**EDIT #4**

Thank you, @Baba and @Quasdunk for the inputs again.

```
 if(isset($_POST[$interest]))
    { 
      foreach ($interest as $interests)
       {
            $interest = $interests . " ,";
       }
    }
```

then in csv, it showed "array", not values of checkboxes, i.e. 1, 2,3,4

```
$csvData = array($name,$email,$comment,array($interest));
```

Where have I gone wrong with this?

**EDIT #5**

Thank you very much, @Baba. I have last question
Do you know by chance how to pass the variable to mail()? For example, after csv is made/written, then mail() should send all the data to user/admin.

So far I got it working but the interest still doesn't show the selected checkboxes - instead print "Array" similar to csv.

$interest=$_POST['interests'];

this is above the forceheader function.

```
$emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
        }
        $subject = 'I Have A Question to Ask from '.$name;
        $thanksubject = 'Thank you for the Form Submission';
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nInterest $interest \n\nComments: $comments";
        $userbody = "";
        $headers = 'From: '.$name.' ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $emailTo;
        //$headers .= 'Bcc: email2@example.com' . "\r\n";
        //$headers .= 'Bcc: email3@example.com' . "\r\n";

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        wp_mail($email,$thanksubject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
```

This is after writing to csv. it would be sent if there is no error such as blank fields. $interest only register one array, for example if I select all checkboxes, it would show all in email. So far I tested and it only show one last checkbox. Do you know where I went wrong?

**UPDATED**

I have figured it out and managed to write the checkboxes' values to csv and emails as well.

Comment: Let me take a wild guess: The problem only appears if there's no comment, right? :) In your `foreach`-loop, you give `$strVal` a new value in each iteration, but you want to concat the string. So, define `$strVal='';` **before** the loop and do a `$strVal .= $val;` (note the period) inside the loop. Also, nothing is written if the file exists... You don't have to check if it exists, `fopen()` creates it for you automatically.

Comment: See updated code for EDIT #2 & EDIT #3

Comment: @Baba - saw the updated code and I tried to modify the code - it worked correctly except the interest part. Is there any way to append the interest array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work , its accepts array and converts it to CSV automatically

```
    $csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);
    $filename='I-have-question.csv';
    $isNew = (file_exists($filename) || is_file($filename)) ? false : true ;
    touch($filename); //Sets access and modification time of file and  If the file does not exist, Create it.
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    if($isNew) //Add header Information if its new 
    {
        fputcsv($fp , array ('NAME', 'EMAIL', 'COMMENT'));
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $csvData);
    fclose($fp);


    //To Force CSV downlaod  
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($filename);
```

A new concept to always force header information even if it does not exist before

```
        $csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);
        $filename='I-have-question.csv';
        $isNew = (file_exists($filename) || is_file($filename)) ? false : true ;
        touch($filename); //Sets access and modification time of file and  If the file does not exist, Create it.
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
        forceHeader(array ('NAME', 'EMAIL', 'COMMENT'),$filename);
        fputcsv($fp, $csvData);
        fclose($fp);




        function forceHeader(Array $headerParam,$csvFile)
        {
            $headerParam = implode(",", $headerParam);
            $fileHeader = file_get_contents($csvFile, NULL, NULL, 0, strlen($headerParam));
            if($headerParam != $fileHeader)
            {
                $content = $headerParam ."\r\n" ;
                $content .= file_get_contents($csvFile, NULL, NULL, strlen($headerParam) + 2);
                file_put_contents($csvFile,$content);
            }

        }
```

==== Interest =====

```
$interest = isset($_POST[$interest]) ? implode("; " , $_POST[$interest]) : array();
$csvData = array($name,$email,$comment,$interest);
```

Thanks
:)

Comment: thanks and i will try this. Also, how to have text appear in columns (name, email and comments) while writing all data into three columns?

Comment: it would appear automatically .. just keep on calling fputcsv($fp, $csvData); to add new $data in the same array format

Comment: I tested, csvData appears in the columns, but not $csvCol = array ('name', 'email', 'comment') at the very top. Is there any way to add the column heading texts in first top row?

Comment: by updating the code? I wonder if print the array into csv but it wouldnt work, I think, right?

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

```
$csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);

$strVal = implode(';', $csvData);

$filename='I-have-question.csv';

file_put_contents($filename, $strVal, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

The reasons why your code does not work:

- You overwrite `$strVal` in each iteration of the `foreach`-loop. But you want to append something:

  `$strVal = ''; 
  foreach(...) {
    $strval .= $val; //note the period
  }`
- This line `if(!file_exists($filename)){` says: Only write something to the file if it does not exist yet. This works exactly once :) But this is not what you want.

Concerning your second question, I'm not quite sure if I get you right. So you want to write the column names to the first line of the file, right? If so, your code could look something like this:

```
$csvData = array($name,$email,$comment);
$csvCol = array ('name', 'email', 'comment');

$filename='I-have-question.csv';

if(!file_exists($filename)){
  //if the file doesn't exist yet, create a new file and write the column names
  file_put_contents($filename, implode(';', $csvCol) . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

file_put_contents($filename, implode(';', $csvData) . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Or, as @Baba pointed out, you can also work with `fputcsv()` instead of `file_put_contents()`:

```
if(!file_exists($filename)){
  //if the file doesn't exist yet, create a new file and write the column names
  $handle = fopen($filename,'w');
  fputcsv($handle, $csvCol,';');
  fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen($filename,'w');
fputcsv($handle, $csvData,';');
fclose($handle);
```

Make sure to choose an appropriate delimiter. The default one is ',' (a comma), but since you're also dealing with user input which might contain commas as well, choosing another delimiter (like ';') might be wiser.

In both cases, the output should look something like this:

```
name;email;comment 
John Smith;john.smith@johnsmith.com;I like cheeseburgers
```

Comment: thanks but one question is how to add the texts for heading in columns at top so that all data goes in each columns?

Answer (score 0):

1. You always need to call `fopen` - even if the file exists. remove the if statement around it.
2. You are just setting `strVal` to the last value of csvData. Just replace the fwrite line with

   fputcsv($filehandle,$csvData);